# Arrange line segments consecutively to make a polygon

Tags: python, polygons, segments

Im trying to arrange line segments to create a closed polygon with python. At the moment I've managed to solve it but is really slow when the number of segments increase (its like a bubble sort but for the end point of segments). I'm attaching a [sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dpmt5ockbvajmgl/AABlBdjk-IvuagCTLEEmpkhia?dl=0) of coordinates (the real ones are really complex but is useful for testing purposes). The file contains the coordinates for the segments of two separetes closed polygons. The image below is the result of the coordinates I've attached.

[image]
This is my code for joining the segments. The file 'Curve' is in the dropbox link above:

```
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple
from random import shuffle
from Curve import Point, Curve, Segment

def loadFile():
    print 'Loading File'
    file = open('myFiles/coordinates.txt','r')
    for line in file:
        pairs.append(make_tuple(line))
    file.close()

def sortSegment(segPairs):
    polygons = []
    segments = segPairs

    while (len(segments) > 0):
        counter = 0
        closedCurve = Curve(Point(segments[0][0][0], segments[0][0][1]), Point(segments[0][1][0], segments[0][1][1]))
        segments.remove(segments[0])
        still = True

        while (still):
            startpnt = Point(segments[counter][0][0], segments[counter][0][1])
            endpnt = Point(segments[counter][1][0], segments[counter][1][1])
            seg = Segment(startpnt, endpnt)
            val= closedCurve.isAppendable(seg)

            if(closedCurve.isAppendable(seg)):

                if(closedCurve.isClosed(seg)):
                    still =False
                    polygons.append(closedCurve.vertex)
                    segments.remove(segments[counter])

                else:
                    closedCurve.appendSegment(Segment(Point(segments[counter][0][0], segments[counter][0][1]), Point(segments[counter][1][0], segments[counter][1][1])))
                    segments.remove(segments[counter])
                    counter = 0

            else:
                counter+=1
                if(len(segments)<=counter):
                    counter = 0

    return polygons

def toTupleList(list):
    curveList = []
    for curve in list:
        pointList = []
        for point in curve:
            pointList.append((point.x,point.y))
        curveList.append(pointList)

    return curveList

def convertPolyToPath(polyList):
    path = []
    for curves in polyList:
        curves.insert(1, 'L')
        curves.insert(0, 'M')
        curves.append('z')
        path = path + curves
    return path

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pairs =[]
    loadFile();


    polygons = sortSegment(pairs)
    polygons = toTupleList(polygons)
    polygons = convertPolyToPath(polygons)
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood by thinking this site is a code writing service. Please see [about] and [mcve]

Comment: @EdHeal Oh! i have not mentioned about providing me any code at any moment. What i'm asking is a way to solve an algorithmic problem. For that reason I wrote the line "Let me know in case you need the code I've written."

Comment: @EdHeal I've modified the post so it stands with stackoverflow posting rules. Thx! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are only looking for the approach and not the code, here is how I would attempt it.

While you read the segment coordinates from the file, keep adding the coordinates to a dictionary with one coordinate (string form) of the segment as the key and the other coordinate as the value. At the end, it should look like this:

```
{
    '5,-1': '5,-2',
    '4,-2': '4,-3',
    '5,-2': '4,-2',
    ...
}
```

Now pick any key-value pair from this dictionary. Next, pick the key-value pair from the dictionary where the key is same as the value in the previous key-value pair. So if first key-value pair is `'5,-1': '5,-2'`, next look for the key `'5,-2'` and you will get `'5,-2': '4,-2'`. Next look for the key `'4,-2'` and so on.

Keep removing the key-value pairs from the dictionary so that once one polygon is complete, you can check if there are any elements left which means there might be more polygons.

Let me know if you need the code as well.

Comment: Thanks @yeniv i'll try what you suggest these days and i'll tell you later if it worked.

Comment: do you think converting the cooridnates to md5 hash codes is better than  comparing strings or Numbers?

Comment: @Pipo, md5 hash is alphanumeric so it would be string comparison again. Also, we are doing dictionary lookups and dictionaries in Python are internally implemented as hash tables (https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2000-March/048085.html)

Comment: @Pipo, hope it worked out for you. Just to test the approach, I had written some code few days back (although not very elegant). In case you want to check the gist: https://gist.github.com/vineyyadav/43eb862e7dcbbdec08374f3b6d1234e0

Comment: HI @yeniv. Actually this is part of a large project im doing so this days i've been focussing in other parts of it, like hardware and so. the next week i'm giving a try on the string dictionary approach you suggested and i'll come back and tell how i did and post the code too. Really appreciate the help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something similar. I needed to turn coastline segments (that were not ordered properly) into polygons. I used [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) to arrange the segments into connected components and order them using [this function](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_preorder_nodes.html?highlight=dfs#networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_preorder_nodes).

It turns out that my code will work for this example as well. I use `geopandas` to display the results, but that dependency is optional for the original question here. I also use `shapely` to turn the lists of segments into polygons, but you could just use `CoastLine.rings` to get the lists of segments.

I plan to include this code in the next version of [PyRiv](https://github.com/jkibele/pyriv).

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import geopandas as gpd
import networkx as nx

class CoastLine(nx.Graph):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Build a CoastLine object.

        Parameters
        ----------

        Returns
        -------
          A CoastLine object
        """
        self = super(CoastLine, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def read_shp(cls, shp_fn):
        """
        Construct a CoastLine object from a shapefile.
        """
        dig = nx.read_shp(shp_fn, simplify=False)
        return cls(dig)

    def connected_subgraphs(self):
        """
        Get the connected component subgraphs. See the NetworkX
        documentation for `connected_component_subgraphs` for more
        information.
        """
        return nx.connected_component_subgraphs(self)

    def rings(self):
        """
        Return a list of rings. Each ring is a list of nodes. Each
        node is a coordinate pair.
        """
        rings = [list(nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(sg)) for sg in self.connected_subgraphs()]
        return rings

    def polygons(self):
        """
        Return a list of `shapely.Polygon`s representing each ring.
        """
        return [Polygon(r) for r in self.rings()]

    def poly_geodataframe(self):
        """
        Return a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` of polygons.
        """
        return gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': self.polygons()})
```

With this class, the original question can be solved:

```
edge_list = [
    ((5, -1), (5, -2)),
    ((6, -1), (5, -1)),
    ((1, 0), (1, 1)),
    ((4, -3), (2, -3)),
    ((2, -2), (1, -2)),
    ((9, 0), (9, 1)),
    ((2, 1), (2, 2)),
    ((0, -1), (0, 0)),
    ((5, 0), (6, 0)),
    ((2, -3), (2, -2)),
    ((6, 0), (6, -1)),
    ((4, 1), (5, 1)),
    ((10, -1), (8, -1)),
    ((10, 1), (10, -1)),
    ((2, 2), (4, 2)),
    ((5, 1), (5, 0)),
    ((8, -1), (8, 0)),
    ((9, 1), (10, 1)),
    ((8, 0), (9, 0)),
    ((1, -2), (1, -1)),
    ((1, 1), (2, 1)),
    ((5, -2), (4, -2)),
    ((4, 2), (4, 1)),
    ((4, -2), (4, -3)),
    ((1, -1), (0, -1)),
    ((0, 0), (1, 0)) ]

eG = CoastLine()

for e in edge_list:
    eG.add_edge(*e)

eG.poly_geodataframe().plot()
```

This will be the result:

[image: Polygon plot]